# Multiple repeated (*ngFor) ControlValueAccessor instances in a form

Tags: angular

I have multiple repeated instances of a `ControlValueAccessor` control in a form, simplified sample code below:

```
<form
  id="form1"
  name="form1"
  (submit)="save()"
  novalidate
  #form1="ngForm"
  [ngClass]="{ 'was-validated': form1.submitted }"
>
  <div *ngFor="let test of tests; let $index = index" class="mb-5">
    <app-test
      id="test"
      name="test"
      [(ngModel)]="test.value"
      #test="ngModel"
    ></app-test>
  </div>

  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

These would bind to a list/array of items, such as:

```
 public tests = [
    { value: 'test one' },
    { value: 'test 2' },
    { value: 'test3' },
  ];
```

However, when embedded in a form, they end up overwriting the value of each other - presumably because they have the same form control name/id inside the child component.

(The actual code is different and a bit more complex)

What am I doing wrong in the component that means I it overwrites the other controls?

Here is a working StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-14-title-demo-tfhvjn

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the repeated controls need unique ids/names:

```
  <div *ngFor="let test of tests; let $index = index" class="mb-5">
    <app-test
      id="test{{$index}}"
      name="test{{$index}}"
      [(ngModel)]="test.value"
      #test="ngModel"
    ></app-test>
  </div>
```